# Cannot install RWeka package in docker image

Tags: java, r, docker

I am using a java image, with R installed as I need it, however when I am installing an RWeka package I get an error

Here is my Dockerfile below:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie-scm

# A few problems with compiling Java from source:
#  1. Oracle.  Licensing prevents us from redistributing the official JDK.
#  2. Compiling OpenJDK also requires the JDK to be installed, and it gets
#       really hairy.

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        bzip2 \
        unzip \
        xz-utils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Default to UTF-8 file.encoding
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# add a simple script that can auto-detect the appropriate JAVA_HOME value
# based on whether the JDK or only the JRE is installed
RUN { \
        echo '#!/bin/sh'; \
        echo 'set -e'; \
        echo; \
        echo 'dirname "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$(which javac || which java)")")"'; \
    } > /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-java-home

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

ENV JAVA_VERSION 7u111
ENV JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION 7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        openjdk-7-jdk="$JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION" \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && [ "$JAVA_HOME" = "$(docker-java-home)" ]

# If you're reading this and have any feedback on how this image could be
#   improved, please open an issue or a pull request so we can discuss it!

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0

# system library dependency for the euler app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmpfr-dev

RUN sudo apt-get install -y \
    r-base r-base-dev

# basic shiny functionality
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# install dependencies
RUN R -e "install.packages('Rmpfr', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Special Package
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinydashboard')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('plyr')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dplyr')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tm')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('SnowballC')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('wordcloud')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('RWeka')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reshape2')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('igraph')"



# copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/testapp1
COPY testapp1 /root/testapp1

COPY Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e shiny::runApp('/root/testapp1')"]
```

Here is the error when I try to install any the RWeka package below:

```
./configure: line 3736: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘RWekajars’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWekajars’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RWekajars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘RWeka’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RWeka’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOdXNMp/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘RWekajars’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("RWeka") :
  installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I resolve this in the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The installation will go through successfully if the command line: `sudo R CMD javareconf` is executed before `RUN R -e "install.packages('RWeka')"`